# How to handle Orientation (Landscape or Portrait ) in ListView using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using ItemTemplate ( that is ViewCell ). I got know about the Orientation article in Xamarin documentation but there is no point about handling ListView orientation.

Hope to get the answer

Screen shots
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkMvC.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PrJj.png

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this? Would you like your listview to work differently based on the orientation or use a different ItemTemplate? It should work like all other UI by default, just resizing to the new dimensions.

Comment: It should resize to new dimensions . As I am using ViewCell I am defining all xamarin controls inside the Grid.

Comment: And in what way does it not resize currently? Can you post a clear description of the problem or even screenshots of the app? You are most likely not using the correct HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your screenshots, this is not an orientation problem, your listview IS the full width in both cases, what is quite possibly wrong are your layout options.
Can you show us your item template definition?

You are using a grid inside the ViewCell?
In that case, first make sure the grid's horizontal options are set to FillAndExpand, then check the grid column size definition.
Can you also show us the grid's column size definitions?

If they all have fixed sizes assigned, then they will always be that size, no matter how much unsued space there is.
There are 2 ways to make them use more space.

If possible, you should use the "star" sizes. This is where you give your columns sizes as portions of the available space.
If you give your first column the size 1*
and the second column size 1*
they will both take exactly half of the available width.

You can use any other numbers to select portions, such as three columns with sizes 5* 3* 1*
Which would make your first column 5 times as big as the third, and the second column would be 3 times as big as the third.
Again, in total, they will take the entire available width.

The second column sizing option is to use "Auto" sized columns, which will size the columns according to the elements inside them. Whatever size the largest element inside that column (in any of the rows) takes, that is the size that column will have.
To take the whole screen width in this case, at least one of the columns content should have "AndExpand" on it's horizontal options.
This is somewhat easier as it will automatically size the columns and you just take care of populating them properly with content, but be wary as this approach is significantly slower.

Finally, if you experience performance issues, consider implementing the ViewCell with an AbsoluteLayout. It can be a bit more pain to set up, but should work faster than grid if you have a bunch of rows inside the list view and a bunch of data in each row.